# Reset iPad when Apple ID no longer exists

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud, apple-id, find-my-iphone

I've read all the techniques to reset an iPad and none of them work. Not only do I not know the password to the Apple ID, the Apple ID doesn't exist at all! It was a former employee's email address. So I just recreated his old email account and registered with Apple as a new Apple ID. But the iPad won't take the Apple ID password I just created...

I can't even sign out unless I turn "Find My iPad" off, but when I turn that off I'm asked for the Apple ID password again. iTunes also makes me turn "Find My iPad" off.

What can I do?